# Extract data from oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

I read a lot about connecting to oracle database from visual studio, and here i am:

```
public string ExecuteSelect(string query)
{
    string result = "";
    int i = 0;
    string oradb = "Data Source=FG50OP02;User Id=****;Password=****;";
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
        {
            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result = result + (string)reader.GetOracleString(i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No rows found.");
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        conn.Dispose();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I get an error

> "ORA-000911 Invalid caracter"

but my query is very simple, "`select AAA from BBB`". And it returns (when i execute it on toad directly) just a flag "Y" or "N".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the exact query you're using.

Comment: It's in your query string contents, not in the code that you've shown us. Are you including a semicolon (";") in your query?  If so, then remove it because they are not allowed in the API calls and will cause this error.

Comment: also if you are planning on storing values from the Database you should create a List<T> of a class or a List<T> of Object if you are wanting to store the values in a string instead of the result = result + (string)reader.GetOracleString(i) look up the string.Join() method also I think that you should not use the GetOracleString method instead qualify the column name that you are wanting to return for example 
`(string)reader["ColumnName"];` can you also show the exact query and where you define it..? also include a `WHERE` clause in the query if necessary

Comment: Great, that was the ";" thing. Awesome. But there is an other issue now. There are 4 colums in the response and one row, and result just return the value in the first column of the first row. With my while i though i'd get everything..
EDIT; i'll try what you said MethodMan and come back to you guys, thx a lot btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, so this works for me:

```
public string[] ExecuteSelect(string query)
    {
        string[] result = { "", "", ""};
        string oradb = "Data Source=FG50OP02;User Id=AUTOEIM;Password=EIM;";
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
            {
                OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result[0] = (string)reader["ROW_ID"];
                        result[1] = (string)reader["NAME"];
                        result[2] = (string)reader["LOGIN"];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No rows found.");
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            conn.Dispose();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

It returns me exactly what is on TOAD.